# 90-percentile for Watts-Strogatz model in R

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph

I have a Watts-Strogatz model with parameter [dim=1, size=100, nei=2, p].
I need to create a plot for

- the diameter
- 90 percentile effective diameter
- the clustering coefficient

At the end "as a function of the rewiring probability p" what does it mean?
What effect can be observed when p is around 0.1?

the code is:

```
i<-0.00
j<-1
a<-data.frame()
while (i<=1){
  temp<-watts.strogatz.game(1,100,2,i) #make graph
  distemp<-(distances(temp)) #make distance table to calculate 90%_eff_dia
  distemp2<-apply(distemp,2,sort,decreasing=FALSE)[1:(length(V(temp))*0.9),] 
  #sort distance table
  distemp2[is.infinite(distemp2)]<-NA  # clensing Inf Value

  a[j,1]<-i
  a[j,2]<-diameter(temp)
  a[j,3]<-transitivity(temp)
  a[j,4]<-max(distemp2[(length(V(temp))*0.9),],na.rm=TRUE) # find 90 eff dia.
  i=i+0.001
  j=j+1
}

colnames(a)<-c('i','diameter','transitivity','eff_dia')
plot(a$i,a$diameter,type='l',xlab='p',ylab='Diameter',col='blue')
plot(a$i,a$transitivity,type='l',xlab='p',ylab='Clustering coef.',col='red')
```

Is it possible way to make it easier? 
I have RStudio version [1.0.136] and package `fastnet` doesn't work for me. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like your question focuses on statistical methodology and so might be better asked on data science SE or on crossValidated. Also, the version that you are referring to [1.0.136] is the version of rstudio, not R. These are two separate pieces of software. Your version of R is probably 3.3.x or 3.4.0.

Comment: oh okay, I will ask on crossValidated.Thx